# Is it ok to use a chat room to help a student practice critical thinking / essay writing for a couple of months?

Tags: discussion

I've been helping a student prepare for some exams in February. As English is not his native language, his initial needs were related to vocabulary and reading comprehension, so we created a chat room on the English Language Learners' SE site. I've also been helping him with essay-writing. We took a break for a few weeks, and now we are resuming, but focusing now more on writing and critical-thinking skills rather than language. The ELL room has been frozen; I could create a new room there, but now our subject matter doesn't fit as well as it did before. Would it be appropriate to create a room on writers.SE?

Comment: why not use google hangouts?

Comment: I hadn't considered that one. I guess I have been unconsciously flattering myself, thinking that perhaps our conversation would be useful to others.

Comment: It stands to reason that if you're helping someone with their writing, doing it using the written word is best because it's more practice _doing_ the thing. As an aside @GreatBigBore, thanks for doing a nice thing. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be fine.  Give it a clear name and description so people browsing our site's chat rooms will know what it is.  Also, it will be public (private rooms are for moderation purposes only), so you might get visitors.  Beyond that, if y'all aren't doing things that attract flags, I doubt anybody will care.